# android get frequencies peaks from mp3

Tags: android, mp3, fft, frequency

im creating android audio player and i want to add the possibility of drawing live chart with frequencies amplitudes (i dont know how it is named exactly). I know how to do it with FFT. But FFT can be applied on raw data only. My player gets mp3's. So how to extract frequencies and their amplitudes from mp3 file?

I see single possible decision: to write own native library that would decompress mp3 file (AFAIK android hasn't tools for decompressing mp3s) and after that to create spectrogram using FFT. 
But this method has one essential minus - it needs large quantity of time. Converting mp3 to wav and applying FFT on full raw data consumes many time. Obviously better to do it on-the-go during playback. But i dont know how to do that.

Are there any other ways to achieve my goal?

P.S. I need something like this[image]

Answer (score 0):

This goal can be achived by using mp3 decoders, for example, [mpg123](https://www.mpg123.de/). It can be build for android and gives possibility for accessing to raw song data. And i've found [this](https://github.com/thasmin/android-mp3decoders) project which use different mp3 decoders.